# Custom functions file issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom-functions.php file in my wordpress theme that seems to be causing an issue once I update Wordpress to the latest version. Can anyone see any errors within this code?

I am getting this error in the log file:

```
` PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare is_iterable() (previously declared in 
/home/smartservice/dev.smartservice.com/wp-includes/compat.php:536) in 
/home/smartservice/dev.smartservice.com/wp- 
content/themes/smartservice/custom_functions.php on line 40 `
```

I'm unfamiliar with Php, but it seems to be outdated. We are using PHP 7.0 on the site where that error shows up.

The code for these lines are **custom-function.php**

```
function is_iterable ( $var ) {
    return ( is_array($var) || $var instanceof Traversable );
}
```

and **compact.php**

```
function is_iterable( $var ) {
    return ( is_array( $var ) || $var instanceof Traversable );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot declare two functions with same name, if you declare, then first function will evaluate and second function will throw error.

Better to Avoid same function names

In your case, Please rename your is_iterator function in custom-functions.php to some other name.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't allow 2 functions to have the same name. Since a core WP file is defining a function called is_iterable(), you will have to rename the one in your custom-functions.php file.

Of course, if your function is identical to the compat.php one then you can safely get rid of yours in favour of the core one.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other 2 answers are "right" there is more to add, and I'm surprised no mention was made of `!function_exists`.

"[is_iterable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php)"  was added as a "built in" function in PHP 7.1; so any fix you make now should cater for moving to a later version of PHP.

[PHP documentation user notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php#122574) include an example of what your code should look like **to work with both PHP 7.1+ AND be backward compatible to PHP 5.6**:

So you need to modify your code snippets in both compact.php and custom-function.php e.g.

```
if ( !function_exists(  'is_iterable' ) ) {
  function is_iterable( $var ) {
    return ( is_array( $var ) || $var instanceof Traversable ); // see note below
  }
}
```

N.B. The documentation example additionally includes ensuring var is an object before checking "traversability"

```
return is_array( $var ) || ( is_object( $var ) && ( $var instanceof \Traversable ) );
```

but I assume this previously worked fine for you without the additional check.

I don't know whether compact.php and custom-function.php files are always both included together in all Wordpress processing - **if so you you only need to modify compact.php and can delete the snippet from  custom-function.php**.